# How to set the default display block position on the time line of highstock charts?

Tags: highcharts, timeline

2 questions about HighStock. As is shown on the code, I just want to use the function zoom in/out on x-Axis by drag the display block on timeline:
1. How could I hide the time shown on the timeline (such as 00:00:00:150)?
2. How to set the display block on arbitrary position (as is always shown on the left of the chart)?

```
$(function () {
    // create the chart
    $('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {
        chart: {
            alignTicks: false
        },

        rangeSelector: {
            selected: 1
        },

        title: {
            text: 'AAPL Stock Volume'
        },

        xAxis: {
            max: 10,
            min: 0
        },

        series: [{
            type: 'column',
            name: 'AAPL Stock Volume',
            data: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
        }]
    });
```

});

[charts of the corresponding code above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V7eYs.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Range of visible x axis can be set via [`axis.setExtremes()`](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#Axis.setExtremes) and to hide labels of x axis in navigator - set `enable` to `false` for them.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/go2pg8t7/

```
$(function() {
  // create the chart
  $('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {
    navigator: {
        xAxis: {
        labels: {
            enabled: false
        }
      }
    },
    series: [{
      type: 'column',
      data: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
    }]
  },function(chart){
    chart.xAxis[0].setExtremes(25,66);
  });
})
```

Comment: @Keith You are welcome. If this answers your question mark it as accepted. If not, please provide more info.